# change navigation drawer selected item on fragment backstack change

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

I have two fragments `FragmentHome` and `FragmentAbout`, I have added `NavigationDrawer` to app when I click `Home` it opens `FragmentHome` and `About` opens `FragmentAbout`, when I open `FragmentAbout` I am also adding it to backstack. This is working fine.

Now the problem is when I click on `About` and press back button it goes to the `FragmentHome` but the `NavigationDrawer` still shows the `About` as selected item, I want to change this selected item to `Home` when I press back button from `FragmentAbout`

Home Activity:

```
public class ActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Drawer layout
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);
    assert drawer != null;
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    // Navigation view
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    assert navigationView != null;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Open first menu item
    navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.nav_home, 0);

    // Set first item checked
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    final MenuItem menuItem = item;

    // Check if menu item is selected
    if (item.isChecked())
        item.setChecked(false);
    else
        item.setChecked(true);

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        // Open home fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new FragmentHome())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        toolbar.setTitle("About");

        // Open home fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new FragmentAbout())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_layout);
    assert drawer != null;
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_layout);
    assert drawer != null;
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

FragmentHome

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.fragment_home_title);
}
}
```

`FragmentAbout` code is same as `FragmentHome` just layout change.

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow but didn't find any solution yet, so if someone know how to do this please tell me.

Comment: the NavigationDrawer still shows the About as selected item..for this are you talking about the toolbar title??????

Comment: @Saurabh No not toolbar title, toolbar title is working as expected, I want to change highlited menu item in drawer to `Home`.

Comment: did you find it ??

Answer (score 15):

There is a OnBackStackChangedListener that you can use for this. Tried it and it works great.

```
public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   this.getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
       new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
          public void onBackStackChanged() {
              Fragment current = getCurrentFragment();
              if (current instanceof MyFragmentA) {
                 navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_myfragA);
              } else {
                 navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_myfragB);
           }
       }
   });
...
}
```

Comment: This method works, but if you use the same fragment for different items, it will be mistaken. Also if you open a DialogFragment (instead of fragment) and close it, this event won't be called.

Comment: @CoolMind for same fragments, you can compare tags

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good solution, but at least it is acceptable for me. You need to store fragment's position inside stack variable (ex: List) whenever a fragment menu is clicked from nav drawer. Then override `onBackPressed` to remove the last value from stack, and set drawer position to the current last value of stack. Here's the example:

```
private List<Integer> itemPositionStacks = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    itemPositionStacks.add(currentSelectedPosition);
}

public void onNavigationViewItemSelected(int itemId) {
        Fragment fr = null;
        switch (itemId) {
            case 0:
                fr = new aFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fr = new bFragment();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fr)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        Drawer.getInstance().setDrawerChecked(itemId);
        itemPositionStacks.add(itemId);
    }

public void onBackPressed() {
        if(itemPositionStacks.size() > 1) {
            itemPositionStacks.remove(itemPositionStacks.size() - 1);
            Drawer.getInstance().setDrawerChecked(itemIdStacks.get(itemIdStacks.size() - 1));
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

In your onBackPressed() function ..
you must choose which item to be selected by using

```
drawer.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
```

and remove the selection of the another item

```
drawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_about).setChecked(false);
```